# Improving the Speed on Exporting Datagridview to Excel with Interop Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I do have a c# window application on a Button Click event which exporting the datagridview to Excel with the Microsoft Office Interop Excel module.

But i found that the time used to export data was quite slow, and i do found that other was using 2D Array method to speed it up. I did try it but i was not able to filter it out correctly.

I did try before to close the Excel Calculation to manual but it still not help. Any advice on this?

Here are my code :

```
//Create Excel Object.
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objexcelapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = objexcelapp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            //objexcelapp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 30;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
            try
            {
                worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
                worksheet.Name = "Daily Report";
                worksheet.Range["A1", "S1"].Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbBurlyWood;

                for (int i = 1; i < dailyReportGridView.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    if (i != 20 && i != 21 && i != 22)
                    {
                        objexcelapp.Cells[1, i] = dailyReportGridView.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                    }
                }
                /*For storing Each row and column value to excel sheet*/
                for (int i = 0; i < dailyReportGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dailyReportGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (dailyReportGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null && j != 19 && j != 20 && j != 21 && j != 22)
                        {
                            objexcelapp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dailyReportGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                            AllBorders(objexcelapp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Borders);
                        }
                    }
                }
                objexcelapp.Columns.AutoFit();  //Auto fit all the data length to the column by Marcus 10-09-2016
                //Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user.
                SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
                if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK && dailyReportGridView.RowCount > 1)
                {
                    workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName);
                    MessageBox.Show("Excel File Had Been Saved!", "Success");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Operation Canceled.", "Failed To Save");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Export Excel Error" + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                objexcelapp.Quit();
                workbook = null;
                objexcelapp = null;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is avoid setting individual cells, since every update you do trigger a refresh for the entire excel-document (not only the worksheet). I think you can turn of refresh (ie recalculating cells), but I don't remember the exact method-name and MSDN seems to be having issues right now. You also want to try to try to set entire ranges instead of individual cells, since setting cells take more time than ranges.

If you want specific help on either of those, I'd recommend you to open new questions for those.

The scope of this question is very broad, but yes, using excel interop sucks balls when it comes to performance and you can find help if googling it.

Comment: Hi , Yup i did googling alot and i found most of them are using range method. Anyway do you mean i turn off the refresh will help?

Comment: Yup, a large part of the time per "set" is the recalculation of reverification of the entire workbook.

Comment: i did try turn it off but still it quite slow when exporting too :(

Answer (score 0):

One of the keys to faster interop is setting entire range values, borders, color, etc. at once instead of cell by cell. You are already doing that for the interior color.

Here is example of setting range of values at once
[How to optimize exporting data to excel in Excel Interop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743077/how-to-optimize-exporting-data-to-excel-in-excel-interop)

Another way is to copy the values and format as html and paste that in Excel:

```
Clipboard.SetText("<table><tr><td>a<td>b"); // most closing tags are optional
worksheet.Paste();
```

Comment: What do you mean by copy the values and format as html?

Comment: @MarcusTan I can't test it, but for example if you copy this text `<table style="border:1px solid red"><tr><td>a<td><b>b` and paste it into Excel, it should show a border around the table and a bold **b**. Or you can try copying some of the examples here http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/tables/html_table_border.cfm

Comment: I tried to use the worksheet range but it seem not working

Answer (score 0):

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

```
        //Adding the Columns.
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv1.Columns)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(column.HeaderText, column.ValueType);
        }

        //Adding the Rows.
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv1.Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value.ToString();
            }
        }



        //Exporting to Excel.
        string folderPath = "C:\\Excel\\";
        if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
        }
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "AssetMaster");

            //Set the color of Header Row.
            //A resembles First Column while C resembles Third column.
            wb.Worksheet(1).Cells("A1:C1").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.DarkGreen;
            for (int i = 1; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //A resembles First Column while C resembles Third column.
                //Header row is at Position 1 and hence First row starts from Index 2.
                string cellRange = string.Format("A{0}:C{0}", i + 1);
                if (i % 2 != 0)
                {
                    //wb.Worksheet(1).Cells(cellRange).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.GreenYellow;
                }
                else
                {
                    ////wb.Worksheet(1).Cells(cellRange).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Yellow;
                }

            }
            //Adjust widths of Columns.
            wb.Worksheet(1).Columns().AdjustToContents();

            //Save the Excel file.
            wb.SaveAs(folderPath + "DataGridViewExport.xlsx");
        }
    }
```